# How to make sure an XML Schema sequence contains at least one element

Tags: xml, schema, xsd

My xml tag is given below

```
<ADCNT>
      <EM>
      <RUID>
</ADCNT>
```

I can make `EM` tag as mandatory also the same thing I can do with `RUID` by providing `minOccurs = 1` (`<EM minOccurs=1>`). But I want if both of them are not present then do not validate the xml against schema. If any one of them is present then validate the xml against schema. Means if `EM` tag is not present then `RUID` tag must be present and vice versa.

So, how to solve this problem?

Thanks
Sunil kumar Sahoo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the issue resolved. It's like Martin v. Löwis' answer, but a little bit different:

```
<xsd:element name="ADCNT">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="EM" minOccurs = "1"/>
                <xsd:element name="RUID" minOccurs = "0"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="RUID" minOccurs = "1"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Comment: <xsd:element name="ADCNT">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="EM" minOccurs = "1"/>
                <xsd:element name="RUID" minOccurs = "0"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="RUID" minOccurs = "1"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

Answer (score 8):

You need to make a choice:

```
<xs:element name="ADCNT">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element ref="EM" minOccurs="1"/>
       <xs:element ref="RUID" maxOccurs="0"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element ref="RUID" minOccurs="1"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Haha, you posted almost the exact same schema (I embedded the `EM` and `RUID` elements directly instead of using a type reference) a few seconds before I did. Deleted my post.
You'd expect there to be a more elegant way to say "exactly one of the elements out of of any of these", but I never heard of one.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got the issue reolved.
<xsd:element name="ADCNT">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="EM" minOccurs = "1"/>
                <xsd:element name="RUID" minOccurs = "0"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="RUID" minOccurs = "1"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
            
            </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>